# Change bootloader of Window 10 with UBUNTU

Tags: windows, windows-10, grub, bootloader, grub2

I have `Windows 10 Build 2004` and `Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop` installed on my System with *BIOS Mode: Legacy*. Both the OS running fine but When it comes to Dual Boot Selection Menu, by default Windows Bootloader first boot the Partial OS and if I select Windows 10 it will boot fast but if I select Ubuntu then System got restart and then Grub comes into play and ask for choosing OS to boot.

Previously I don't know how? but before upgrading to `Windows 10 build 2004` from `Windows 10 1909`, I had a Dual Boot Menu Option like of Windows 7 dual boot menu. Whatever OS I choose for booting no **Reboot/Shutdown** Takes place.

How can I achieve with now? Somebody help!

Here is the Bootloader Style I have:

[image: BootLoader I Have]

Here is the Bootloader Style I Want:

[image: BootLoader I Want]

Comment: This will enable the legacy bootloader, but I don't know if it will pick up your Ubuntu installation automatically. See steps at: https://winaero.com/blog/enable-the-legacy-windows-7-like-boot-menu-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou guys for all your efforts and contribution. But I have got another solution within Windows.
The bootloader I was using was Windows 10 **Metro Bootloader** coming in Windows since Initial release of Windows 8. I can Switch to Old Windows 7 Style Bootloader with just a command with Admin Rights ie.:
`bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy`

For Switching back to default Style:
`bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standard`

Few More Commands for More Actions:

```
To enable advanced options in Windows 8 boot menu:
bcdedit /set {globalsettings} advancedoptions true

To enable editing of kernel parameters at startup:
bcdedit /set {globalsettings} optionsedit true

To disable Windows 8 logo in boot screen:
bcdedit /set {globalsettings} custom:16000067 true

To disable text messages in boot screen:
bcdedit /set {globalsettings} custom:16000068 true

To disable circle animation in boot screen:
bcdedit /set {globalsettings} custom:16000069 true
```

Please Upvote My Answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading, Windows probably installed it own bootloader, so that you need to
restore GRUB.

You may do it in Linux from the command line, using the command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Replace `sda` by your disk as required.

You may also use the Ubuntu boot media:

- Boot from the Ubuntu CD/USB.
  A Live USB can also be used.
- Install and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
- Click "Recommended Repair"
- Reboot. If the GRUB boot menu does not appear, hold
  <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>
  while booting and you should be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I have 2 HDD, one contains Ubuntu, and other have Windows. i just want Windows 7 Style dual boot menu

Comment: You only have two choices now : Windows 10 or Linux GRUB. There are other bootloaders, but you will find it complicated to install and still another style screen.

Comment: I have edited my Question and Placed images please check. In Simple words i want bootloader to be lite.

Comment: Trying to use the Windows 7 bootloader with Windows 10 is a dangerous experiment that can end with an unbootable computer.

Comment: i just want the UI like windows 7 bootloader. not the bootloader from windows 7. regardless of its windows bootloader or grub

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible if you wish to keep Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

In BIOS settings, you should put the hard disk with Ubuntu as the first boot option, immediately followed by the hard disk with Windows. If Ubuntu detects another startup disk (aka Windows) (works even if system is on another disk), it should automatically show a bootloader. The bootloader looks *lite* as you requested, and from there you can choose to boot into Windows or Ubuntu (default is Ubuntu, can be changed).

I've tried this on Fedora/ Windows 10 dual boot, and it works completely fine. I don't know about Ubuntu though.